# How do I zoom in?

Tags: dota-2

Is there any way to zoom in the camera in DotA 2? The characters are really small on my screen and I cannot enjoy the special items for cosmetics. I have found a zoomed-in screenshot, however, there is no visible HUD. Any tips?

[image: a zoomed-in screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, you can zoom in and shift your camera's perspective slightly by using your mouse's scroll wheel. Scroll forwards to zoom in, scroll backwards to zoom out.

Comment: Not just *by default*. The zoom feature can't be removed from the wheel at all.

Comment: Wrong! it can be changed with `dota_camera_disable_zoom 1` in the console or in the autoexec.cfg (to make it permanent)